# Eclipse: Package explorer not showing packages in flat structure

Tags: eclipse

[image]

Please see the image above.  Why is eclipse not showing packages in the 'flat' structure as opposed to the 'hierarchical' structure?

Comment: Its does. Show us what you think is wrong rather than the menu option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your project of type Java or J2EE.  As packages are related to Java specific projects only and not related to other types of projects, say C++, you won't see packages in flat structure if your project is not of type Java.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what happened.

It is because the project is NOT a Java project.  Since packages are specific to Java, Eclipse does not show the packages in the flat structure in this case.